# How to complete the name of a user type dynamically in ORACLE?

Tags: oracle

I have several user-defined types in PL/SQL packet:

```
TYPE blk_esta IS RECORD (
   codi_mone  VARCHAR2(1),
   codi_situ  VARCHAR2(1),
   situ_pig   VARCHAR2(1),
   IMPORTE    NUMBER(11,2)    
);

TYPE oper_data_mv_out IS RECORD
(
  bloq_esta  blk_esta,
  bloq_aseg  blk_aseg
);
```

I have a BBDD with the names and fields order. So I obtain then name of the first field and I want to assign dynamically a value.

```
select name into field from GFM_MODEL;
```

I have tried several things:

```
sql:= 'SELECT ''E'' into oper_data.bloq_esta.'||name||' from dual';
execute immediate (sql);

out: ORA-00905: missing keyword

sql :='oper_data.bloq_esta.:b1:=''E''';
execute immediate (slq) using in out oper_data;

out:PLS-00457: expressions have to be of SQL types
```

Any idea how I could do this?

Thanks in advance.

Edit: I need it because my struct is much bigger than the example, I want to define the model of the struct in a table with `code_bloq`, `name_bloq`, etc. And when someone needs to add a new field, only have to insert in the table. And the program reads in the table the new field and no need to modify the code. Look the struct:

```
TYPE oper_data_mv_out IS RECORD
(
  bloq_esta  blk_esta,
  bloq_aseg  blk_aseg,
  bloq_toma  blk_toma,
  lista_bene tabla_bene,
  bloq_plan  blk_plan,
  lista_inte tabla_inte,
  bloq_tari  blk_tari,
  bloq_hist  blk_hist,
  bloq_resc  blk_resc,
  bloq_repr  blk_repr,
  bloq_fide  blk_fide,
  bloq_comu  blk_comu,
  lista_cuen tabla_cuen,
  bloq_cumu  blk_cumu,
  bloq_part  blk_part,
  bloq_esp2  blk_esp2,
  bloq_esp3  blk_esp3,
  bloq_esp4  blk_esp4,
  bloq_esp5  blk_esp5,
  bloq_esp6  blk_esp6,
  bloq_esp7  blk_esp7,
  bloq_esp8  blk_esp8,
  bloq_esp9  blk_esp9,
  bloq_esp10 blk_esp10,
  bloq_esp11 blk_esp11,
  bloq_esp12 blk_esp12,
  lista_blk_camp tabla_blk_camp,
  lista_blk_warn tabla_blk_warn  
);
```

Other solution could be assign the data with other references... instead of `oper_data_mv_out.bloq_esta.(1)`. Any idea?

Comment: BBDD = database; Learn something new every day.

Comment: Why do you want to do dynamically?

Comment: BBDD is 'BAse de Datos' in spanish... like DB is database. Sorry :)

Comment: I need to make it dynamically because I have big structs of data (user defined types) and I split the incoming message in my struct. I want that if tomorrow, someone add a field in my struct, he doesn't need to modify the code, because the code knows all the fields in the struct. Only need to insert a record in the table with de model of the struct.

Comment: Look my struct is much bigger than the example type:

TYPE oper_data_mv_out IS RECORD
(
  bloq_esta  blk_esta,
  bloq_aseg  blk_aseg,
  bloq_toma  blk_toma,
  lista_bene tabla_bene,
  bloq_plan  blk_plan,
  lista_inte tabla_inte,
  bloq_tari  blk_tari,
  bloq_hist  blk_hist,
  bloq_resc  blk_resc,
  bloq_repr  blk_repr,
  bloq_fide  blk_fide,
  bloq_comu  blk_comu,
  lista_cuen tabla_cuen,
  bloq_cumu  blk_cumu,
  bloq_part  blk_part,
  bloq_esp2  blk_esp2,
  bloq_esp3  blk_esp3,
  bloq_esp4  blk_esp4,
  bloq_esp5  blk_esp5,
  bloq_esp6  blk_esp6,
...
);

Comment: "if tomorrow, someone add a field in my struct, he doesn't need to modify the code" *That* is what you should be asking for: "How can I allow someone to modify the structure of the incoming data and I can still process it later". To me, that sounds like an XML project.

Comment: `execute immediate sql_str into function(name)` where function dynamically returns record type based on passed argument.

Comment: @fg78nc, functions in PL/SQL cannot return variable type results.

Comment: @nop77svk functions in PL/SQL do return variable type results.

Comment: @fg78nc, yeah, sure, OK. Feel free to answer the question with a working proof of concept based on your `execute immediate sql_str into function(name)` code snippet. I'll happily upvote your answer if it's working in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, redeclare your packaged (PL/SQL record) types to schema-level (SQL object) types.

Then your code

```
sql :='oper_data.bloq_esta.:b1:=''E''';
execute immediate (slq) using in out oper_data;
```

should work... with a slight modification, of course...

```
sql :='
    declare
        l_oper_data     oper_data_mv_out := :oper_data;
    begin
        l_oper_data.bloq_esta.'||field_name||' := ''E'';
        :oper_data := l_oper_data;
    end;
';
execute immediate sql
    using in out oper_data;
```

**A proof of concept**

First, the schema-level type...

```
create or replace type obj_so_variable_field_name
as
object (
    field_1                     varchar2(32),
    field_2                     varchar2(32),
    field_of_corn               varchar2(32),
    field_of_maze               varchar2(32),
    fieldy_of_korn              varchar2(32)
);
/
```

Now the dynamic field modification...

```
declare
    l_record                    obj_so_variable_field_name := new obj_so_variable_field_name(null, null, null, null, null);
    l_field_to_change           constant varchar2(30) := 'field_of_corn';
    l_value_to_change           constant varchar2(32) := '42';
begin
    dbms_output.put_line('*** before the change');
    dbms_output.put_line('>'||l_record.field_1);
    dbms_output.put_line('>'||l_record.field_2);
    dbms_output.put_line('>'||l_record.field_of_corn);
    dbms_output.put_line('>'||l_record.field_of_maze);
    dbms_output.put_line('>'||l_record.fieldy_of_korn);

    dbms_output.put_line('*** now changing '||l_field_to_change||' to value of "'||l_value_to_change||'"');
    execute immediate '
        declare
            l_oper_data             obj_so_variable_field_name := :oper_data;
        begin
            l_oper_data.'||l_field_to_change||' := :in_value;
            :oper_data := l_oper_data;
        end;
    ' using
        in out l_record,
        in l_value_to_change
    ;

    dbms_output.put_line('*** after the change');
    dbms_output.put_line('>'||l_record.field_1);
    dbms_output.put_line('>'||l_record.field_2);
    dbms_output.put_line('>'||l_record.field_of_corn);
    dbms_output.put_line('>'||l_record.field_of_maze);
    dbms_output.put_line('>'||l_record.fieldy_of_korn);
end;
/
```

... which, upon running, yields...

```
*** before the change
>
>
>
>
>
*** now changing field_of_corn to value of "42"
*** after the change
>
>
>42
>
>
```

Comment: Thanks, from ask TOM answer me that we should use object types but don't give me an example so I tried with select into and neither works.